# $p$-groups as specific central quotients

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

There are $p$-groups such that they can not be isomorphic to $G/Z(G)$ for any group $G$. Perhaps such thing may not arises if we replace $Z(G)$ by a term of lower central series. Then my question is the following:

**Question:** Is there an example of a *non-cyclic* $p$-group $H$ such that $H$ can not be isomorphic to $G/\gamma_k(G)$ for some $k\geq 2$?

I was feeling that answer should be NO, but I don't know how to prove if it is so.

Comment: Do you want to assume $\gamma_k(G)$ is nontrivial?

Comment: @Derek Holt: yes;

Comment: I don't think this is possible with $H=Q_8$.